# Is it possible to use relative path for mesh filename in URDF?

Tags: urdf, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have my mesh STL in the same directory as my URDF so I was hoping I could reference it via a relative path.

This works as expected

```
<mesh filename="package://urdf_tutorial/urdf/Assy_X.stl" />
```

But I would like to do something like this

```
<mesh filename="file://Assy_X.stl" />
  or this
<mesh filename="file://./Assy_X.stl" />
```

Where it assumes the mesh path is relative to the URDF path.

Is this possible somehow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263308/is-it-possible-to-use-relative-path-for-mesh-filename-in-urdf?/) by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2017-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While not a perfect answer to my original question as it requires a one time adjustment to a launch file, this post (http://answers.ros.org/question/38956/pass-parameters-to-xacro-in-launch-file/) helped solve my problem pretty well by allowing me to pass an argument to the xacro, which can then be used in the xacro.

This allows the urdf/xacro to be oblivious to its location as the launch file will ensure it knows where to find the STL & DAE files I specify.

Added "meshDirectory" argument to the launch file

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" default="$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/test2.xacro meshDirectory:=$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/" />
```

Used it like this in .xacro

```
<geometry>
    <mesh filename="file://$(arg meshDirectory)Assy_X-1.stl" />
</geometry>
```

---

Originally posted by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) with karma: 86 on 2017-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. Afaik that is not supported.

Do you have a specific reason for wanting to do this, or is it just convenience?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on 2017-06-07**:
Mostly a convenience issue, to prevent modifying the filenames when I share my urdf & stl files with others loading the urdf in a different package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
Far from me telling you what to do / how to structure your packages, but when models are supposed to be re-usable / composable, using `xacro` is recommended. If you then use `package://` relative urls, there should be no need to rename / modifying filenames?

**Comment by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on 2017-06-07**:
Good point.  I created an application to build URDF from an Autodesk Inventor model, so didn't see a need for xacro as if I needed to make any adjustments, I would do that in the Inventor model and the urdf would rebuild.
Trying xacro now.

**Comment by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on 2017-06-07**:
I tried xacro, without much success.
${cwd), prints the directory rosrun/roslaunch is ran from, so that didn't work
$(find package), would appear to still require changing the xacro file to current users' package.
Am I overlooking something here?  I'm very new to ROS so sorry if this is silly.

**Comment by [Dale McConachie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30596/dale-mcconachie/) on 2017-06-07**:
You could probably include a parameter to you xacro file called "pacakge_name" or something like that which can then be set in one spot when someone invokes the xacro file. This at least alleviates the issue.

**Comment by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on 2017-06-07**:
Thanks Dale, that would definitely make it easier.
I've found another solution to my problem that involves passing an argument to the xacro from a launch file; I've posted the details in another answer to make it easier for others to find.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-08**:
I'm still rather confused why you'd want to do what you are doing, but if it works for you then that's fine.

As a final note: urdf is not designed to be composable, xacro is. Reusable artefacts are supposed to live in reusable pkgs, and to reuse them you reference them in composite xacros ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-08**:
.. by their `package://..` relative uris and then instantiate them. Any resources they might need (material defs, meshes) are placed in the containing pkg and their location resolved at tranformation time.

Following this pattern typically removes the need to edit paths completely.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-08**:
You might want to take a look at some existing xacros to get a good idea for this.

`xacro` is definitely not a panacea, but resource management is quite ok.

Perhaps if you can describe your workflow in a bit more detail we can see why you need to copy urdfs and update package names.

**Comment by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on 2017-06-14**:
@gvdhoorn I can understand your confusion and appreciate your well informed and continued input. My use case is very likely an unusual scenario. I'm developing an application to export urdf from a popular CAD system, Autodesk Inventor.

**Comment by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on 2017-06-14**:
As such I have many, many iterations of tweaking my CAD model and exporting to URDF to test in RViz to ensure I completely capture all possibilities of URDF. As well I would like to hand the files off to others running RViz to test without needing them to build/update a package.

**Comment by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on 2017-06-14**:
The work flow I'm using here is likely not the best, but so far it has worked well for quickly iterating and testing my URDF.  I will look more into the xacro/package solution mentioned above when I have a bit more time.  Thanks again for the insight.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-14**:
Ok, that makes things a bit clearer.

Btw: `package://` links can/are still used in plain urdfs as well. Would that not make things slightly more reusable? `file://` links aren't very portable.

Finally: looking forward to that exporter. I can see a lot of use for it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For all those wondering why you could ever need using a relative path to point to the mesh geometry file, here is a standard use-case: you want to import into the scene an object that someone shared with you. You would normally want to copy only the geometry file (STL) and the meta-data regarding the visua/collision/inertia aspects (URDF). Creating a XACRO file or a package is superfluous.

---

Originally posted by [Mihai](https://answers.ros.org/users/43230/mihai/) with karma: 21 on 2022-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

If you use xacro, then you can do the following:

```
<xacro:property name="XACRO_DIR" value="$(cwd)/${xacro.abs_filename('.')}" />
```

then

```
<mesh filename="file://${XACRO_DIR}/Assy_X.stl" />
```